# How can I make the OS not consume the keyboard event but first give it to the running application

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Recently I switch from Unity to Gnome 3. Now some very annoying behavior started to take place! For example I work in some application that has an internal keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Alt + L. I press that combination and what happens... Lock Screen!!! Same behavior happens also for other key combinations.

How can I make the OS **not** consume the keyboard event but first give it to the running application?